# Schrodinger's equation

Tags: beamer, math-mode, fractions

Trying to get Schrodinger's equation to format better.  The first term is

```
-\dfrac{\hslash^2}{2m} \, \dfrac{\mathrm{d}^2 \psi}{\mathrm{d} x^2}
```

However, because of the exponent in the denominator, the second fraction prints lower than the first one, and looks unbalanced.  Is there a way to drop the baseline for the exponent of the first fraction so they line up?  Also, this is in beamer, if that adds other complexity to the issue

Comment: Regarding physics: Keep in mind, that the spacial derivative is only a partial derivative, hence use `\partial` instead of `\mathrm{d}`.

Comment: Yes, but we're just working in one dimension, so \mathrm{d} is proper.

Answer (score 2):

`\vphantom` can be used in the denominator of the first fraction to line to increase the height to the height of the second denominator.

Because we have fractions with superscripts, it becomes a little more complicate, because TeX changes into the "cramped" math style, where the
superscripts are less raised. Therefore the example calculates the height in macro `\crampedvphantom`. The macro uses `\overline` to force TeX to change the math style into its cramped math style for the expression in the argument.

In the example I have increased the height of the second denominator a little to make the effect more visible:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\crampedvphantom}[1]{%
  \mathpalette\cramped@vphantom{#1}%
}
\newcommand*{\cramped@vphantom}[2]{%
  \sbox0{$#1\overline{}$}%
  \sbox2{$#1\overline{#2}\m@th$}%
  \dimen0=\ht2 %
  \advance\dimen0 by -\ht0 %
  \ht2=\dimen0
  \hbox{\vrule width0pt height\dimen0 depth\dp0}%
}

\begin{document}
\[
  -\dfrac{\hslash^2}{2m \crampedvphantom{\partial x^{2^{1^1}}}}
   \, \dfrac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x^{2^{1^1}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Perhaps the OP meant `\mathrm{d}^2` instead of `\mathrm(d)^2`?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Yes, this makes sense. The example also now uses `\partial` (see Henri Menke's comment/answer) and takes into account the "cramped" math style.

Comment: I agree.  The \vphantom solves it nicely, even works in beamer, and can adjust for super or subscripts.  I used the simple differential \mathrm{d} because we're at the beginning of the course, still working the basic examples in 1 dimension.

Comment: Yes, of course, \mathrm{d}.  Edited in OP, thanks.